# C#: How to check that string is a two digits hexnumber?

Tags: c#

in my function i have a string parameter which normally represents a two digits hexadecimal number like 5E or 0A
How can i check if this string is really a number and nothing else (like G9 or NB or abcdef) and that all characters are written in big (A instead of a)?
Thanks for help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957908/can-any-of-the-net-parse-methods-handle-a-hex-string-prefixed-with-0x

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service. Also, do you want just want to check or force it to be uppercase?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Are you aware that you can get an individual character from a string using the indexer, and you can compare characters with `>=` etc? (You could also potentially use a regular expression, but I'm not sure I would...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *regular expression*:

```
  String source = "AC";

  Boolean result = Regex.IsMatch(source, "^[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}$");
```

In case you accept *uppercase* hexadecimal symbols (`A..F` but not `a..f`) only

```
  Boolean result = Regex.IsMatch(source, "^[0-9A-F]{2}$");
```

If you accept one symbol hexadecimals (e.g. `A`, `0`, `C`) as well as two-symbols (`AA`, `3F`, `02`)

```
  Boolean result = Regex.IsMatch(source, "^[0-9A-F]{1,2}$");
```

Comment: Please note that the OP is asking for uppercase validation. Also, he is stating that the input "*normally*" represents a two digits hex number, but not **always**.  `{1,2}` would probably be a better idea.

Answer (score 2):

How about regular expressions?

```
private bool IsHex(string input, int maxDigits = 2)
{
    return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) && 
           maxDigits > 0 &&
           Regex.IsMatch(input, String.Format("^[A-F0-9]{{1,{0}}}$", maxDigits));
}
```

You can leave the default of 2 digits maximum, or you can specify your own limit:

```
bool result = IsHex("AF", 1); // Yields false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for this.

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[0-9a-f]{2,2}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match m = r.match(someStr);
```

you can then from this tell if there your string is a hex value

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool IsTwoDigitsHexNumber(string s) {
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) &&
        s.Length <= 2 &&
        s.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'F');
}
```

Comment: It should be `c >= '0'` and `c <= 'F'`

Comment: Please explain why your code fixes the problem and in addition Thomas should be thankful for having somebody writing his code for free.

Comment: @StephenReindl You should put your comment under the other answers too, then.

Comment: @StephenReindl and FYI: I wasn't going to answer at first, but then the 3 other answers appeared, so then I thought it was probably ok.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your specific end goal is, the easiest thing is probably to try to format it, and handle an exception.

```
Convert.ToInt32(yourString, 16)
```

Then just catch the potential FormatException, which is thrown if

> value contains a character that is not a valid digit in the base
>   specified by fromBase. The exception message indicates that there are
>   no digits to convert if the first character in value is invalid;
>   otherwise, the message indicates that value contains invalid trailing
>   characters.

There are cases where this won't cover your possible requirements though, like if you need to make sure that there are only two digits in your hexadecimal number. You could check if the returned int is in the correct range, but it reducec the overall simplicity of this approach. I still like it better than the regex, though. The code will be easier to read for most people also, as regexes sometimes are not very intuitive to understand just looking at it.

This does not account for case sensitivity though, but most scenarios won't care about that, and if the end goal is to present the numbers, or pass them on to a third party where it does matter, just send the string as upper case.